# MacBook Pro 13" 2015 CPU and GPU temperatures

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, temperature, gpu

I've noticed that my new MacBook Pro 13" 2015 (MF839) is getting hot while playing browser games or watching models at sketchfab.com. Both CPU and GPU temperatures rise to 100-105 degrees (Celsius) while playing agar.io or petridish.pw (for example) in Safari/Google Chrome. I've already reset SMC controller and cooler is working fine: about 3000 RPM, but I still believe that temperatures are very high for browser games.

Does anybody else have similar experience? Should I contact the Apple Center or it is a normal experience having such temperatures? I do not plan to use a MacBook for playing, just would like to know if it is a hardware problem, issue, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The high temps are mostly because of flash. Had a simmilar problem with my 15" macbook. I bought a fitting screw driver from amazon for 3€ opened and cleaned my mac and the temps went down by about 10°. Try it out it could help.

Comment: In my case it is not flash, but WebGl, canvas, etc. Macbook is a several month old so it's not caused by dust. Thanks for the reply, anyway. = )